# Algorithm for Penalty Calculation in delay payment (Month)

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm developing an application in C# and MySQL. I need help creating a function to calculate penalty for delayed payment with interest.

Given:

- A is the amount to pay (1000)
- I is the interest for delayed payment (1%)
- P is the resulting penalty

The logic of the calculation should be:

- if one month delay for A=1000,  P should be 10  (1000/100 *1%)
- if two months delay for A=1000,  P should be 10 + 20 (twice the Previous month Penalty)
- if three months delay for A=1000,  P should be 10 + 20 + 40
- etc.

I don't have any idea how to implement this. Any expert's ideas will be helpful for using either a stored procedure (MySQL) or functions in C#.

ACUBE.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [sum of finite geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum).

In your case *a* is 1% (*baseInterest*), *n* is number of months and *r* is penalty multiplier.

So your interest percent calculation will look like (in C#):

```
var interestPercents = baseInterest * (1 - Math.Pow(penaltyMultiplier, delayInMonths))/(1 - penaltyMultiplier);
```

And then you just multiply the amount by the resulting percent.